# What are the advantages gain by defining a template function with static and inline in a source file(cpp)?

Tags: c++, templates, linker, inline, static-linking

Assume that we have define a template function in a X.cpp source file as below:

```
/............. X.cpp .........................../
template<class Container>
static inline void foo(const Container& container,std::string& content)
{
     /.../
}
```

1. Do we gain any compiler/linker optimization using `static` and `inline` here?
2. If we have considerable amount of template functions definitions in a `cpp` file,will this affect to reduce build time for each translation unit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do we gain any compiler/linker optimization using static and inline here?

Not likely. The `static` qualifier makes the template function have internal linkage. Meaning that the name `foo` will refer to it only inside the translation unit of `X.cpp`. If that very same definition appears in `Y.cpp`, it's a different template function for all intents and purposes.

The `inline` specifier is probably a misguided attempt to encourage the compiler into inlining the call. Since compilers do it even without the specifier, and can even ignore it if they choose to, it's pointless. The most one can say is that it clarifies intent. But YMMV on how good an idea it is.

> If we have considerable amount of template functions definitions in a cpp file,will this affect to reduce build time for each translation unit?

Don't try to do the compiler/linker's work for them. Specify the linkage that *makes sense*. Put the definition in a header/cpp file based on the same rationale, and let your build system work.

If you artificially start making templates static and including them in different translation units, your compiler/linker is very likely going to err on the side of caution and blow up your executable size.

Comment: Teller, Thanks for the quick reply,and If I only use `X.h` with `X.cpp` is it not wise to think of internal linkage and use `static` ? right?

Comment: @BuddhikaChaturanga - A header implies eventual intent to include it in more than one translation unit. If the templates are truly "for  `X.cpp` only", I'd just define them there to begin with (static and all). Otherwise I'd place them in the header, without `static`.

Comment: thank you very much got it..you are actually a story teller specialized for cpp ;)

Comment: @BuddhikaChaturanga - As far as C++ goes, I hope I'm more a supplier of facts and wisdom, than wild stories :) But thank you nonetheless!

Comment: by the way bro,C/C++ like an ocean,I think you cannot end telling story about them :D . Every four years new concepts,features and standards.